# bootstrap pagination is overflowing parent div dependant on resolution, how to shrink it or line break it?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im using boostrap4 theming for my pagination, I've come across an issue when loading the page on smaller resolutions than my monitor whereby the paginate is exceeding the parent div and making for ugly viewing.

here is my sample code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <h3 class="text-capitalize">Devices</h3>
    <ul id="pager_device" class="pagination-sm mt-1 pagination"><li class="page-item first disabled"><a href="#" class="page-link">First</a></li><li class="page-item prev disabled"><a href="#" class="page-link">Previous</a></li><li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">1</a></li><li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">2</a></li><li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">3</a></li><li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">4</a></li><li class="page-item next"><a href="#" class="page-link">Next</a></li><li class="page-item last"><a href="#" class="page-link">Last</a></li></ul>
    <div id="pager_content_device">

        <div class="col-12 results item active">
            <div class="pt-4 border-bottom">
                <a class="page-url h4 text-primary" href="/config/device_details/460/118/">US-EDGE</a>
                <p class="page-description mt-1 text-muted"> Location: US <br> Serial: XXX <br> Version: 1<br> Install Date: 01/01/2019</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 results item">
            <div class="pt-4 border-bottom">
                <a class="page-url h4 text-primary" href="/config/device_details/5/1/">UK-EDGE</a>
                <p class="page-description mt-1 text-muted"> Location: UK <br> Serial: XXX <br> Version: 1<br> Install Date: 01/01/2019</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's some screenshots when testing against a phone or an iPad

against a phone the col width is 12 and you see if leaving the col
[image: phone]

looking against multi cols on an iPad resolution its a mess of paginators overlapping
[image: mutli cols]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Pagination</h2>
    <ul class="pagination pagination-separate pagination-curved synchronized-links">
      <li class="page-item first disabled"><a href="#" class="page-link">First</a></li>
      <li class="page-item prev disabled"><a href="#" class="page-link">Prev</a></li>
      <li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">4</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">5</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">6</a></li>
      <li class="page-item next"><a href="#" class="page-link">Next</a></li>
      <li class="page-item last"><a href="#" class="page-link">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: which part of the code makes the paginator stay within the div? I copied the ul classes but it didn't make a difference